# Why doesn't the Sendto() syscall return the number of sent bytes?

Tags: sockets, go, network-programming, system-calls

In Go's standard library, the networking syscall `Sendto()` looks like this:

[Windows](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows#Sendto):

`func Sendto(fd Handle, p []byte, flags int, to Sockaddr) (err error)`

[Unix](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Sendto):

`func Sendto(fd int, p []byte, flags int, to Sockaddr) (err error)`

However, the underlying system call returns the number of sent bytes on all operating systems ([Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto), [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto#return-value)), so why does Go return only an error?

Comment: Probably a mistake when doing the `sendto` design. The return value is often important. `Sendmsg` likewise should return the number of bytes sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really should—but often, you can get away without it.

I said in a comment that the return value is "often" important, but that's probably too strong a claim.  Note that each OS may have subtle differences here; I'm going to describe a traditional behavior from long ago:

1. `sendto` on a stream-type, connected socket (`SOCK_STREAM` with `AF_UNIX` or `AF_INET` etc) is basically the same as `send`: it loops, sending part of the data, until some interesting event occurs.  Interesting events include, but may not be limited to, these:

   - all data are sent
   - a signal interrupts the sending
   - the connection is reset by the other end

   At this point the `sendto` call returns.  The return value is `-1` with error `EINTR` if *no* data were sent, or a short count if some data were sent, but not all data.  This behavior is identical to that of the `write` system call.
2. `sendto` on a stream-type but unconnected socket just fails with `ENOTCONN`.
3. `sendto` on a connected datagram socket errors with a complaint that it's already connected (`EISCONN`).
4. `sendto` on an unconnected datagram socket temporarily connects it (for the duration of the call), sends the message as a single datagram and succeeds and returns the sent length, or fails and sends nothing and returns -1 and `EMSGSIZE` or some other more appropriate error (e.g., if the connect fails or the target host rejects the packet or whatever—though not all of these errors can occur on all protocols).
5. `sendto` on a `SOCK_SEQPACKET` socket (packetized stream-like entity) acts kind of like `SOCK_STREAM` except that either the entire message goes as a single packet, or the send fails entirely.

So, except for case 1—`sendto` on a `SOCK_STREAM` socket that might get interrupted—the return value is always either `len` or `-1`.  For case 1, you can just call `write` instead.  The `EINTR` case should never happen in normal use in Go, because the Go runtime directs all signals to a dedicated OS-level thread within the process, which means the only time you can get a short return is when some data get sent and then the remote host abruptly closes (and resets) the stream.  Even if `EINTR` *does* happen, an OS `write` will produce the correct return value.

The `sendmsg` system call is more complicated because it allows for so many flags, and has different return values on different systems.  The BSD documentation says that it returns the number of *messages* sent while the Linux documentation says that it returns the number of *bytes* sent.  The various message flags are also rather OS-dependent.  A simple wrapper like the Go one can't really hide these differences easily.  (However, I see the Go library has [`SendmsgN`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#SendmsgN) anyway.)